# microsoft graph webhook unconsistent notification delay

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I have set up a microsoft graph webhook to monitor changes in messages, with my application, that was working great in production.
What is happening is the webhook is not sending notifications as quickly as I would expect it to send its notifications. Sometimes it is immediate, sometimes it takes an hour, I do not understand why this is happening.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks subscriptions expire after a certain time and/or if your webhook crashes often or takes too long to reply on regular basis.
You need to renew your subscription on regular basis in order to keep it going.
You can find more information about that here https://www.eliostruyf.com/creating-and-renewing-your-microsoft-graph-webhook-subscriptions/
**I don't think you should be expecting any guaranties that the notification will be instantaneous (or almost).** The reason is all that works with a message queue pattern and a reduce pattern behind the scenes. Notifications are async, and can be delayed depending on the service, on the number of notifications to go to the same subscriber and so on

Comment: Yes, I understand how the webhooks work. My webhook is returning a response very quickly, and the webhook is not crashing. What is happening is the webhook is not sending notifications as quickly as I would expect it to send its notifications. Sometimes it is immediate, sometimes it takes an hour, I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: I proposed an edit for your question to make it clearer.
I don't think you should be expecting any guaranties that the notification will be instantaneous (or almost). The reason is all that works with a message queue pattern and a reduce pattern behind the scenes.
Notifications are async, and can be delayed depending on the service, on the number of notifications to go to the same subscriber and so on.

Comment: I approved the changes, thank you for that, I am fairly new to SO so I am learning how to best ask my questions, didnt realizeI could edit like that. That makes sense, and is what I figured, just would be nice to get more frequent updates.

Comment: Welcome :)  
I edited my answer to reflect our last comments, as you are new to SO, when you find an answer that answers your question you can mark it as answer (green tick mark next to the answer)